# Classloader problem with Websphere 6.1 version

Tags: websphere

Hi 
I have ear application, inside ear i have 4 web modules.  What values i have to set for Classloader mode and WAR classloader policy?  Currently it is giving exception ClassNotFound Exception with the values Classloader mode:PARENT_FIRST and WAR classloader policy:module.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think we will need more information on this question. You can always look into the log and provide more details here; a stack trace is always helpful (but do massage it if it contains confidential information). The class not found error might not relate to class loader at all, I personally encountered class not not found exception when my expanded files are not set in correct permission.

Answer (score 0):

could you elaborate on which class is not found, and on which WAR/JAR it is actually in, and then which one is looking for it.

The solution might end up moving the "missing" class to a separate JAR which the WARs will reference.